# Typescript unable to infer that the iterator value in a for...in loop is a keyof the iterated object

Tags: typescript

I came across a peculiarity in Typescript's (in)ability to infer the types of object fields in `for...in` iterators. Here's an example with comments:

```
// Here I define some interface with arbitrary fields
interface Rule {
    field: boolean
}

// This is a factory function, which allows optional overrides in the signature.
// I'm constraining the overrides object to only permit fields which are also on Rule
function createRule(overrides: { [f in keyof Rule]: Rule[f] }): Rule {
    const base: Rule = {
        field: true
    };

    // Now I try to iterate over the overrides' fields...
    // But the field iterator defaults to type string - it fails to infer that 
    // field can only be a keyof Rule, despite the type constraint on overrides
    for(const field in overrides) {
        base[field] = overrides[field]; // TS7017: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type '{ field: boolean; }' has no index signature.
    }

    // Doing this hairy type cast is a workaround...
    for(const field in overrides) {
        base[<keyof Rule>field] = overrides[<keyof Rule>field]; // But doesn't this seem kinda redundant??
    }

    return base;
}
```

I'm wondering if I'm completely missing / misusing something here, that there's perhaps a more clean / idiomatic solution for resolving this particular Typescript error without the need for (what seems to me) these redundant type casts.

Any ideas?

Comment: [Relevant comment with explanation for this behavior](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/12253#issuecomment-263132208)

Comment: @jcalz it seems like it should work though - from your link: "Note that the changes we made to for-in specifically apply only when objects have a type parameter type. In for (let x in obj) ... where obj is of type T, **if T is a type parameter we infer keyof T for x, but otherwise we infer type string**"

Comment: But the type of `overrides` is not a generic type parameter; it’s a concrete type.